# Floating Too Far Right

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6, css-float

I've got a record management web application which displays a master record on one screen and AJAXes dynamically built editors into an editor div, which I've used JQuery to make draggable. That works.

Even though the div isn't a window, I thought it might be a nice idea to make it act a bit more like one, so I coded in a "close" button. The structure looks like this:

```
<div id="editor">
  <div id="draghandle" />
  <div id="closebutton" />
  <div id="editorbody" />
</div>
```

Editorbody is variable-dimension depending on what people are trying to enter.

Draghandle's width is set at 100% of editor. Closebutton is set up in CSS as `float:right`.

My problem is that, in IE6 and IE7, the close button floats too far right. It's always against the right edge of the window, no matter where I drag the editor div around to. In Firefox and Safari it looks like I expected it to - the window is as wide as editorbody and closebutton sits in the top right corner.

I'm not particularly attached to float:right, just looking for a way to set up the CSS that'll give me the same result across all browsers. Any ideas?

#### "Screenshots"

Here's a mockup of what I'd like to do on jsbin (thanks, redsquare)

[sample code](http://jsbin.com/ikaka)

I'm working with legally sensitive information so I can't provide screenshots of the app. I have, however, taken some shots and blocked out the text and interface, leaving only the window structure.

[how it looks in IE7](http://i278.photobucket.com/albums/kk93/Glazius_bucket/InIE7.png)

[how it looks in firefox 3](http://i278.photobucket.com/albums/kk93/Glazius_bucket/InFirefox.png)

Comment: can you dummy this up maybe on jsbin.com or pastebin.me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to consider just using a [JQuery Dialog](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog) instead since its premade and the styles already work cross platform.

Comment: Thanks! Man, and the next thing I was going to do with this was make a model lightbox-type thing too!

Answer (score 6):

For the record, what worked to fix this was changing the CSS for closebutton from

```
float: right;
```

to

```
position: absolute;
right: 5px;
text-align: right;
```

This produces proper results in IE, and with a little padding for the internal form fields there's no worry about overlap.

Comment: Well this really helped as changing the 'px' of 'right' does the job

Answer (score 0):

CSS hacks are needed sometimes:

```
* + html #editor #closebutton /* IE7 */, * html #editor #closebutton /* IE6 */ {margin-right: 100px;} // insert whatever value that fits here
```

Comment: But #editor is draggable wherever on the page people would like to put it. They can put it up against the right edge of the window. Even if I work relocation of the close button into the editor's drop code -- hmm. 

I have an idea for something that may work now.

Comment: Nope. Setting the width of the editor div to the width of editorbody after it renders still makes it far too wide. Thought I had something there.

Answer (score 0):

for IE specific css hacks you can do something like:

```
#divId {    
   margin-right: 0; /*Normal styles for all browsers*/    
  *margin-right: 100px; /*The asterisk allows only for IE6 AND IE7 to read this*/        
  _margin-right: 90px; /*The underscore allows only IE6 to read this style*/    
}
```

Just make sure the asterisk and underscore hacks are placed after the normal (valid) css style.