# ie7 weird float right problem

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, css-float

here is the html code that is giving me problem in IE7

```
<div style="position:absolute;top:276px;left:194px;" class="drag layer_3">
<img class="deleteitem" height="12px" width="12px" title="Remove" src="/static/redclose.png" style="float:right;cursor:pointer;">
<img src="/static/18.png"  >
</div>
```

this is how it is supposed to look, and it looks fine in ie8, firefox

http://img200.imageshack.us/img200/189/ie8.png

but in IE7, the float right image jumps to the right end of the document like this

http://img33.imageshack.us/img33/6239/ie7bug.png

how do i fix this? i tried removing the height width attributes and use max-height,max-width. that did not help.
thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question might have been answered here: [Floating Too Far Right!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428862/floating-too-far-right)

He suggests using jQuery to do this, since it is written to be browser-independent.

Also, see the original author's solution at the bottom (not using jQuery).

Comment: this fixed the problem for me.


position: absolute;
right: 5px;
text-align: right;

Answer (score 2):

You could either set the width of the div explicity or reverse the order of the images and float left instead of right:

```
<div style="position:absolute;top:276px;left:194px;" class="drag layer_3">
    <img src="/static/18.png" style="float:left"  >
    <img class="deleteitem" height="12px" width="12px" title="Remove"
         src="/static/redclose.png" style="cursor:pointer;">
</div>
```

Comment: hei nick thanks for this! i used this on the redclose and it worked.

    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;
    text-align: right;

Answer (score 1):

I believe the element in question is floating to the right of the parent of "drag layer_3", once you have made someone an absolute position its taken out of the normal document flow.

Answer (score 1):

I think we need to see .drag and layer_3. At the moment I can see no defined width for Remove's parent. I believe the width of your div might be different in ie7. Try adding a border to it to see its computed width.