# margin auto + float right not working in IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, css-float

I have a problem in HTML, when rendering in IE7.
When combining a "margin:auto" block along with a "float:right" block.

This is a sample code for this issue:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="floating" style="float: right; background-color: #ccf">
This is the top right links block
</div>
<div id="body" style="width: 800px; margin: auto; background-color: #fcc">
This is the body.
This is the body.
This is the body.
This is the body.
This is the body.
This is the body.
This is the body.
This is the body.
This is the body.
This is the body.
</div>
</body>
```

Problem with this code in IE7:

- the margin:auto is not centering the block "body". It looks like the block "floating" is somehow affecting the centering

what I get in IE7:

[image: div "body" is not centered]

The correct display will be (div "body" centered):

[image: div "body" correctly centered]

- the "floating" block is not actually floating over the body, when collapsing

what I get in IE7:

[image: div "floating" do not float]

correct display:

[image: div "floating" correctly floating]

Has anyone run into this kind of problem?
Any hint to get this right on IE7?

Thank you

Comment: looks fine to me, however i can only test by putting IE9 into IE7 rendering mode. the only difference appears to be that IE7 puts more of padding/margin on the body, this can easily be corrected with a reset stylesheet

Comment: Added some pics to clarify the issue

Comment: @mr.nicksta - there are significant differences in rendering between IE7-compatibility mode and a real copy of IE7, so if you're only testing your site for IE7 by using IE9's IE7-mode then you're likely to be less compatible with IE7 than you think you are. I suggest downloading a tool like [IETester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage) which lets you use the real IE7 rendering engine.

Comment: To make things easier, I have pasted the code sample from the question into a JSFiddle page: http://jsfiddle.net/E6c9g/ -- IE7 does indeed render it differently to other browsers. I'm afraid I don't really have a solution for you but I hope that makes things easier for others to have a go at it.

Comment: I just posted the images with the right display expected for this code

Comment: @Spudley - i am fairly confident that IE7 rendering mode in IE9 is more accurate than IETester. I have used IETester and the likes before and they can be wildly inconsistent. A [recent article from smashing magazine confirms this](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/09/02/reliable-cross-browser-testing-part-1-internet-explorer/). the Author writes-off IETester completely, and talks slightly more favourably about rendering modes (though has gripes with that also). personally, i trust MS to deliver a better experience than a 3rd party tool

Comment: I haven't tried IE9's IE7 mode, but I was under the impression it's identical to that of IE8. You're right that IETester also gets some things wrong, but it is at least using the right rendering engine. All I can give is advice from my own experience: for the site I'm working on, IETester provides a more accurate simulation of IE7 than IE8's IE7 mode, which for us renders the site significantly differently to a real IE7. Your milage may vary, but that's my experience.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the two divs in a containing div.  Give the wrapper width: 100%; or whatever total width you want.  So you code should look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper" style="width: 100%;">
 <div id="body" style="width: 800px; margin: auto; background-color: #fcc">

/*---- Moved element ---- */
  <div id="floating" style="float: right; background-color: #ccf">
  This is the top right links block
  </div>
/*---- End Moved element ---- */

 This is the body.
 This is the body.
 This is the body.
 This is the body.
 This is the body.
 This is the body.
 This is the body.
 This is the body.
 This is the body.
 This is the body.
 </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't really understand it but you can either wrap it in a div or give the body tag a width of 100% or whatever size you want.  it's usually good to give the body tag a width of 100% anyway and hen set a wrapping div to style the width of the box.

Comment: tried this but didn't work. I have added some pics to the question to better explain the issue

Comment: I think you are waning the element to be floated to the right but inside the body is that correct so that the div id=floating is at the right side of the body.    Please look at the updated code

Comment: I am afraid this does not fix the problem. We want the div "floating" to float beyond the 800px (which is the width for the "body" div). Depending on the browser screen, the "floating" div can be actually floating over the "body" div or to the right of the screen (outside the "body" div).

Comment: I just added some pics to the question with the right visualisation to show the intended display result.

Comment: I did a quick search and it looks like the only real way to do this is with positioned elements or jquery.  Here is a link to another post regarding a similar issue.  [reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/428862/floating-too-far-right) From experience positioning elements can cause other headaches with cross browser compliance though that is getting less and less now with the newer browsers.