# Clean CSS fix of IE7's 'float: right' drop bug

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, css-float

I continuously find myself having problems with elements floated right in IE7.

I have read many Stack Overflow questions which are similar to this one but there doesn't seem to be any consistently clean CSS answers.

What I mean by this is is I want to see answers which **DO NOT change the HTML**. E.g:

- Put the floated element first
- Add a 'clear: both' div after the floated element.

I understand that sometimes the floated element doesn't account for its parents height and therefore sometimes fails to contain it properly. Occasionally I find myself 'adding layout' to an element with zoom: 1 which sometimes fixes it. Other times I find myself messing about in a conditional IE7 style-sheet which isn't the best fix in my opinion.

Note: What I mean by 'having layout' - http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html

I have also read other answers to do with using relative and absolute positioning (parent div and child div respectively). This pulls it up but often affects surrounding divs.

I would be happy to add a bounty to this question if someone can give an in depth explain as to the reasons this happens and a detailed  discussion of the various fixes, **IDEALLY CSS ONLY!**

Many thanks!

EDIT

The most common problem I encounter is when I have something like this:

Left Sidebar - Main - Right Sidebar

Right will often drop when floated. Ideally this should be in the format Left - Right - Main, but I continuously find myself styling developers work (Drupal mainly) where this is the case and it is too much hassle to get them to change their work. Make sense? Because I'm styling developers work they never put the clear block in too (which personally I think is horrible and dirty anyways!)

Comment: This should be obvious that since IE7 doesn't parse some css styles properly, there cannot be an answer that does not change the html.

Comment: What problems are you having exactly? Can you post a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Hey Rick!  Is there a particular context that you're looking for?  So are we talking about the `float: right` issue within items you're trying to lay out side by side?  Or maybe one element in context of a group that you're trying to pull out and have sit to the right of all of them?

Comment: This is still a problem in IE 11.  My "arrow", which is just a class that defines: float:right; is dropping down to the next line on the right.  This does not occur in Chrome and Firefox.  IE is obviously still terrible, even in Windows 10.  Anyway, adding overflow:auto to the parent container stops the drop.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### Introduction

Your title indicates a desire to see a fix for the `float: right` drop bug, but your text implies some broader scope desire to see solutions to “problems with elements floated right in IE7.” There are many general problems with floated elements (`right` or `left`) in that browser. Even though one may question whether support of the IE7 browser is worthy of much attention any more, it undoubtedly will remain so for some people for some time. Therefore, I’m going to take the opportunity here to address numerous issues at once regarding floats in that browser. Note that many experiments and references below come from an excellent resource: http://www.brunildo.org/test/index.html.

### CSS for the Containing Element

For a containing parent to the floated element the following css should be set:

```css
.container {
    overflow: auto; /* forces clearing of the child float */
    zoom: 1; /* give it layout (this can be some other css that does likewise) */
}
```

Making sure it hasLayout is important to prevent types of margin and padding errors, a type of peek-a-boo bug, and allowing the `overflow` to clear. For a sequence of floats, some html may need changing if `padding` on the container is desired to work properly.

With regards to one “drop” issue with a `float: right`, you may want to avoid setting an explicit `height` or `max-height` on the container. A `min-height` is okay. Setting a `height` and then having the `float` be taller than the container makes IE7 not behave with following elements. There is no pure css solution that I have found noted.

If the container is itself `position: absolute` there can be issues with positioning a float that may require that float itself to be set to `position: absolute` instead of being floated.

References:

- For `overflow` to clear -- http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html
- Margins -- http://www.brunildo.org/test/IEFloatAndMargins.html
- Peek-a-boo -- http://www.brunildo.org/test/iew_boo.html and http://www.brunildo.org/test/iew_boo3.html
- Float sequence padding -- http://www.brunildo.org/test/IEmfloa.html
- Avoiding `height` -- http://austinmatzko.com/2007/07/25/internet-explorer-7-float-bug/, http://www.brunildo.org/test/fenc7.html (and his similar problem link on that page).
- Container is `absolute` -- [Floating Too Far Right!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428862/floating-too-far-right)

### CSS for the Floated Child

For a the floated child element, the css (besides `float: right`) to set depends on two things:

**Absolute Container**

Again, as noted above, a containing parent that is `absolute` may require a change in how the child is handled.

**Float is Also a Clearing Element**

If the `float` is also going to have a `clear` set on it, then there are numerous issues that can arise depending totally upon the `html` and `css` of the elements around it. There is no single canonical fix, so look at the references below.

References:

- Container is `absolute` -- [Floating Too Far Right!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428862/floating-too-far-right)
- Also having `clear` -- http://www.brunildo.org/test/IEWfc.html, http://www.brunildo.org/test/IEWfc2.html, http://www.brunildo.org/test/IEWfc3.html

### CSS for Child Elements of Container Before the Float

If the `float: right` follows an element in the `html` structure that should be to its left (and not above it), then that preceding element(s) must be `float: left`.

### CSS for Child Elements of Container After the Float

**A Clear Element**

For an element *after* the `float` that has `clear` set, then if it has `padding` *and* `background-color`, make sure it also hasLayout to avoid a doubling of the `padding`; also this prevents extra space above the `clear` due to container `padding`, and avoids other `margin` issues.

References:

- For `padding` -- http://www.brunildo.org/test/IEClearPadding.html and http://www.brunildo.org/test/IEFloatClearPadding.html
- For `margins` -- http://www.brunildo.org/test/Op7_margins_float.html (look down the page for IE7)

**A Paragraph Before a Clear Element**

Having a paragraph with a `margin-bottom` and shorter in height than the `float`, located between the floated element and a clearing element, can create an extra gap between the `clear` and the `float` equal to that `margin`. There is no known pure css fix other than giving the paragraph a zero bottom margin (which may not be acceptable if the paragraph may go taller than the float).

Reference:

- Paragraph following -- http://www.brunildo.org/test/IEFloatClearMargin.html

### Conclusion

I cannot guarantee I have addressed every issue that may occur with a right floated object, but certainly many major ones are covered. As to “why” these things happen, it is all “bugginess` in IE7.

Comment: I think the `float: right; display: inline;` thing fixes an *IE6*  bug, which was fixed in IE7 (so it's not relevant to the question).

Comment: Please explain why this still occurs in IE 11.  The containing element still needs overflow:auto to prevent a float right element from dropping down... something that does not occur in Firefox or Chrome.

Comment: @Triynko: I cannot answer your question. I'm not nearly as active in webdesign as I used to be, so I am not very familiar with IE11 (and this answer is about IE7!). I suggest you post a new question about the issue you see with IE11 (perhaps cross-referencing this answer if you are in fact seeing similarities). It could be that IE11 has reintroduced some bug here, or it may be similar in effect, but a completely different cause.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use the clearfix solution to collapsing divs? There are variations on this and there is a newer version but I don't have the url to hand, but this is standard clearfix css which you add to the parent element that is collapsing and causing issues with floated elements http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html. Chris Coyer has a better version here http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/.

You say "I understand that sometimes the floated element doesn't account for its parents height and therefore sometimes fails to contain it properly" this is kind of true, the parent will collapse if all child elements are floated. This is due to the elements being removed from the normal flow, when this occurs the parent div is unable to calculate its height and collapses as if there isn't anything inside of the div.

But without seeing the page and the issue you are having I can only estimate that the issue is due to IE6-IE7's haslayout property which is really annoying, they sorted it out from version 8 upwards but it does add extra development time to your build.

But in most situations the clearfix solution is best as it doesn't add extra markup to the page such as

```
<div style="clear: both"></div>
```

this is old and out of date and should be avoided.

I hope this helps you, if you need any more information or I have not answered the question just ask.

Answer (score 0):

We have been using the clearfix solution for years now.

```
.cf:after { content: "."; display: block; clear: both; visibility: hidden; line-height: 0; height: 0; }
.cf { display: inline-block; }
html[xmlns] .cf { display: block; }
* html .cf { height: 1%; }
```

This is a simple CSS class which, ideally, has to be applied to a container that has any child float elements. Since you're restrictive about not changing the HTML at all, you can either:

1. replace all occurrences of `.cf` with your own div's selector [or]
2. use JS to apply the class (which is bad because users will see a broken layout a few seconds until the page loads completely) [or]
3. use PHP `ob_start()` + regex to apply the class [or]
4. just go vintage and rewrite everything using tables (as we used to do in the `90s)

Answer (score 0):

It's simple:

Where you have `float:right`, add `*clear:left`.
Or where you have `float:left`, add `*clear:right`.

`*` for IE7-

Or for validation
`*+html .class{clear:left/right}`

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a year since this was posted, but I found a solution that I like for this. The gist is using 'expression' tag in your CSS for IE7 only to move the floated element to be the first element of the parent in the DOM. It will be semantically correct for all other browsers, but for IE7 we modify the DOM to move the floated element.

In my case, I have:

```
<div>
    <h1></h1>...<p>any other content...</p>
    <small class="pull-right"></small>
</div>
```

In my CSS for pull-right, I use:

```
.pull-right {
    float:right;
    *zoom: ~"expression( this.runtimeStyle.zoom='1',parentNode.insertBefore( this,parentNode.firstChild ))";
}
```

The result is that IE7 moves my `<small>` to be the first element of `<div>` but all other browsers leave the markup alone.

This might not work for everyone. Technically, it is modifying the markup but only in the DOM for IE7 and it's also a javascript solution.

Also, I understand there may be some performance issues with expression (it's slow), so perhaps it's not ideal there are a lot of floats like this. In my case, it worked well and allowed me to keep semantically correct HTML.